# admob ads are not displying (blank screen) in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, admob

I'm working on **AdMob** to display the **ads** in my app using https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals and tried this [video tutorial also](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fv7EgypK4Oc)

am not getting any errors but it not dispalying any ads(showing blank screen) and i have tested both emulator, device getting same result

how to display the adds in my app using AdMob

downloaded latest Sdk [form this](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download#downloadwp7)

Thanks in advance